# Enable Chrome to cache everything

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

Is there an option or a command line for Chrome to force to cache everything, even for a *no-cache* resource? I tried to use a Chrome Extension which modifies response header - however this no longer works, Cache-Control header cannot be modified.

Comment: Extensions can still modify cache headers. Use chrome.declarativeNetRequest as shown in the documentation. In case it doesn't work add an [MCVE](/help/mcve) to the question.